# console.dir in JS vs dir in Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am coming from a JS background and I am currently learning Python. I noticed that when I print dir(10) using python I get all the methods that live on the object.

In JS if I run console.dir(10) I don't get all the methods that live on the number prototype chain.

If everything in JS is an object just like in python why is this the case? Was it just implemented this way or there some background to this?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any extra background info here. Two development teams built what they thought was needed for their respective implementations.

Comment: The browser console implementors decided not to show the prototypes of primitive JS types.

Comment: You can always use `console.log(Number.prototype)`